# Obtengo un IOException a utilizar nominatim.openstreetmap

Tags: android, map

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android en donde utilizo OpenStreetMap. a través de mi ubicación, intento obtener la dirección de la calle enviando coordenadas a **nominatim**, pero termino recibiendo un "IOException: error 403" en el imputStream. Además, ¿si existe alguna otra forma mejor de obtener datos de una URL?

**URL**

```
String requestString = "https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=" +
            latitud + "&lon=" + longitud;
```

**Asynctask**

```
public static class getAddress extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... requestString) {


        String jsonResponse = "";
        String URL = requestString[0];
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(URL);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {

            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String inputLine = "";
            while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(inputLine);
            }

            jsonResponse = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

            return response;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error", "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("Error", "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject response)
    {
        try
        {
            //Resto del código
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no he usado nominatim, pero, no te falta el nivel del zoom en la url?

Comment: Lo he agregado, aún así sigue el problema.